# SQL server - SELECT a columns entry on a CASE WHEN query

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, min, case-when

I'd like to find out the first provider (`PROVIDER_ID`) to the client (`CLIENT_ID`) in a database table of bookings (`BOOKING_ID`)

I currently `SELECT` the `CLIENT_ID` first, then calculate various other things.

I group by (`CLIENT_ID`) and the count is correct.

What I'm looking for is

```
SELECT case when(min(BOOKING_ID)) then PROVIDER_ID else null end)
```

But I am unable to perform sub queries within the `SELECT/CASE WHEN`

I hope this makes sense and the question is clear.

Ideally I would like a solution that is within a single `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get the PROVIDER_ID for the MIN(BOOKING_ID) grouping by CLIENT_ID the following should work:

```
SELECT  
    Client_ID,
    Booking_ID,
    Provider_ID
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Client_ID,
        Provider_ID,
        Booking_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client_ID ORDER BY Booking_ID) as RowNumber
    FROM
        Bookings
    ) OrderedTable
WHERE   
    OrderedTable.RowNumber = 1
```

How does it work? `ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY field)` gives you the row number if the result set was ordered by a particular field. The `PARTITION BY field` allows you to partition the table by a particular key (in this case Client_ID) that will reset the ROW_NUMBER for each Client_ID (so if RowNumber = 1, it's the first entry for that particular client)

More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Using WITH syntax:

```
WITH OrderedTable AS
(
    SELECT 
        Client_ID,
        Provider_ID,
        Booking_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client_ID ORDER BY Booking_ID) as RowNumber
    FROM
        Bookings
) 
SELECT 
    Client_ID,
    Provider_ID,
    Booking_ID
FROM
    OrderedTable
WHERE
    RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Hi Shaun, this is fantastic. I'm really pleased. For anyone else with same issue, I make an error by using the name header (in my case b.) in the second select - which caused an error - Thanks also for the link - Will prove really useful in future